# Find all the homomorphisms from $D_8 \to \mathbb{C}^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-homomorphism

> Find all of the homomorphisms from $D_8$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$.

So far I have:
$\phi : D_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$

$\phi(a)^4 = 1$ so $\phi(a) = \pm 1, \pm i$

$\phi(b)^2$ = 1 so $\phi(b) = \pm 1$

and $\phi(ab)^2 = 1$ so $\phi(ab) = \pm 1$

but $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ (as it is a homomorphism) 
and $\phi(a)\phi(b) \in \{1, -1, i, -i\}$

So does this mean that I have it wrong? And how do I actually write my answer?

Comment: It's not as simple as sending elements to elements that have the same (or smaller dividing) order. You really need to find the normal subgroups to ensure you've gotten all of the homomorphisms, and that makes it easier to determine what they would be.

Comment: Note they have to contain the commutator subgroup since the target is abelian.

Comment: @MattSamuel - can you expand on why they need to contain the commutator subgroup? I don't know this fact!

Comment: @MattSamuel - why do I need the normal subgroups and not just the generators?

Comment: Why do you think you have it wrong?

Comment: @lhf - because I get that $\phi$(ab) =$\pm$1 and shouldn't it be {$\pm$1 and $\pm$i}?

Answer (score 1):

Here we realize $D_8$ in terms of its usual generators and relations:

$$D_8 = \langle a, b : a^4 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = 1 \rangle .$$
Note that by using the relations, we can write any element of $D_8$ as $a^l b^m$.

The conditions $\phi(a)^4 = 1$ and $\phi(b)^2 = 1$, which imply $\phi(a) = i^r$ for some $r$ and $\phi(b) = (-1)^s$ for some $s$ are consequences of the fact that the usual generators $a, b$ of $D_8$ respectively have orders $4$ and $2$. Since (1) a group homomorphism $\phi$ is characterized by its action on a set of generators, and (2) any homomorphism $\phi : D_8 \to \Bbb C^{\times}$ is given by $$\phi(a^l b^m) = \phi(a)^l \phi(b)^m = i^{rl} (-1)^{sm},$$ but not all such maps need be well-defined! To check which are, we must check which satisfy the remaining relation, that is, which satisfy $\phi((ab)^2) = \phi(e) = 1$. Expanding gives $$1 = \phi(abab) = \phi(a) \phi(b) \phi(a) \phi(b) = \phi(a)^2 \phi(b)^2 = \phi(a)^2,$$ so in fact, $\phi(a) = (-1)^t$ for some $t$.

**Remark** The second-to-last equality in the last display equation above uses that $\Bbb C$ is abelian; for the same reason, any homomorphism $G \to H$ into an abelian group $H$ must contain the commutator subgroup in its kernel. Indeed, the last display equation can be written as $1 = \phi(a^2)$, and the commutator subgroup of $D_8$ is $[D_8, D_8] = \langle e, a^2 \rangle \cong \Bbb Z_2$, so we could have used this fact earlier to deduce this tighter restriction on $\phi(a)$. We can conclude from this that all homomorphisms $G \to H$ into an abelian group $H$ are lifts of homomorphisms $G / [G, G] \to H$; in this case, $D_8 / [D_8, D_8] \cong \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: aren't there an infinite number of isomorphisms into $C^\times$ by simply taking the mapping onto the unit circle and then changing the radius of the circle? I'm not sure how we can "count" these

Comment: Certainly not: Any homomorphism $\phi: G \to \Bbb C^{\times}$ must map $e_G \mapsto 1$, so if $G$ is finite, $\phi(G)$ is contained in the unit circle.

Comment: Ahh, neat-o. I didn't realize that the complex multiplication structure would limit you that much. In that case, are there any other homomorphisms other than the (direct) morphisms of the normal subgroup into the unit circle?

Comment: @Travis - thank you for your answer! Does this mean that there are only 2 homomorphisms? When $\phi$(a) = 1 and when $\phi$(a)= -1 ?

Comment: @Jessie What about the possibilities of $\phi(b)$? Note that any dihedral group $D_{2k}$ admits a special homomorphism $D_{2k} \to \{\pm1\} \leq \Bbb C^{\times}$ that maps rotations to $+1$ and reflects to $-1$. (This can viewed in a natural way as the restriction of the sign homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn} : S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ that maps even permutations to $+1$ and odd ones to $-1$.)

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I'm not sure what you mean by "(direct) morphisms of the normal subgroup into the unit circle".

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

As you have noticed, you need to satisfy all relations that define $D_8$:

- $\phi(a)^4 = 1$ so $\phi(a) = \pm 1, \pm i$
- $\phi(b)^2$ = 1 so $\phi(b) = \pm 1$
- $\phi(ab)^2 = 1$ so $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab) = \pm 1$

These imply that $\phi(a) \ne \pm i$ and so $\phi(a) = \pm 1$.

That's all. There are thus $4$ homomorphisms: $a,b \mapsto \pm 1$ independently.

Comment: Ok, so then do I just write the homomorphisms as:  (a,b) $\rightarrow$ (1,1) and (a,b) $\rightarrow$ (1,-1) and (a,b) $\rightarrow$ (-1,1) and (a,b) $\rightarrow$ (-1,-1)

Comment: @Jessie, exactly.

Comment: i have just confused myself, how do these point to the complex plane? Do we take the a as the real number and the b as the imaginary???